# what is the logic behind not requiring admin password for adding login items on macOS?

Tags: macos, applications, security, password, administrator

I've recently installed steam by just copying app folder to applications and was surprised to discover that app automatically added to login items after first run. I didn't expect that to happen. It seems that adding app to login items doesn't require admin password.

- I'm curious, what's the logic behind such design decision?
- Any other places macOS apps can sneak that I should be aware about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login items are per user. As for other user-level settings there is no admin password required to change them. It is a bit sneaky from Steam to add an entry there without informing/asking the user though.

For a lot more ways (including some really sneaky ones) to start applications automatically see https://theevilbit.github.io/beyond/.